# How do I deploy an Asp.Net Core app on a web farm?

Tags: asp.net-core, msdeploy, web-farm

Currently we have 4 separate IIS servers all running behind an HA Proxy load balancer.  With Traditional ASP .Net, we've been taking a web deploy package and loading them to the first server, and then just using MSDeploy to sync all of the servers to the first.  Almost all of our deploys are virtual directories, not web sites.  And those virtual directories are assigned to an established app pool.   This has been working well for some time now.   For those rare times where we need to create a new application pool, we log into each web server independently and create the app pool.  These app pools run a specific set of credentials.

With an ASP .Net core app, it seems there are 2 different issues now to address:

1. Since Kestrel fires up, how do we get the kestrel part of the
   virtual directories to shut off so we can sync the servers up.   We
   really don't want to have to log into each server independently to
   shut them down.
2. It seems that the preferred method is to create
   an individual app pool for every ASP .Net Core app.  In our case, on
   our current environment, if everybody started rewriting their apps
   in ASP .Net Core, we've have about 200 app pools (and growing).  It
   isn't possible for one giant app with all of the virtual directories
   in it.  They are managed by different teams. So is there a way to
   sync the app pools (with a specific set of credentials) across
   servers in a farm?

Thanks, 
Nick

Comment: 1) The app offline page is honored in the same way, so I don't think that's a new problem, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy 2) There seems to be no good solution for pool identity management, but you might use PowerShell remoting to automate the steps.

Comment: Instead of create many app pools, would be better to create maps inside the app for routing to any app module, therefore no need to create app pool for each app module created. However that needs to create any custom mapper associates to traditional asp.

Comment: There isn't really one master app though.   So having a route to route to individual modules would be problematic.    The nice thing is, group A could right a new ASP .Net app and we just add it to the virtual directory and away it goes.

The individual app pools is a guideline from Microsoft.   Their docs say to create the equivalent of a virtual directory in a sub-app and put those in their own app pools.